# Denormalizing Data with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a StudentDetails table like follows:

[image]

And a StudentResults table like follows:

[image]

I want to build a query that outputs the following:

[image]

So effectively I want to combine the data of these two tables in a denormalised manner. I've tried using PARTITION BY with a Pivot but I haven't been able to get close to the result. Is there a simple way to make this query? Thanks

Comment: PIVOT should be the answer. Can you show me you PIVOT query

Comment: Yes you can use a crosstab query (aka conditional aggregation). You can also use a dynamic pivot but I find the syntax for PIVOT to be really obtuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the so-called `pivot` problem. There are several ways to solve it. SQL Server has even a [special feature for it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

The basic idea is to to a `group by` to collapse the rows, and the a `filtered` aggregate:

```
SELECT StudentID
     , MAX(CASE WHEN term = 1 THEN result END) Term1Result
     , MAX(CASE WHEN term = 2 THEN result END) Term2Result
  FROM StudentResults
 GROUP BY StudentID
```

This result can then be joined to the StudentDetails.

Here is an article I wrote on the pivot problem in SQL:

- http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Answer (score 3):

Do a `left join` for each term:

```
select d.StudentId, d.Name, d.Course, r1.result as Term1Result, r2.result as Term2Result
from StudentDetails d
left join StudentResults r1 on d.StudentId = r1.StudentId and r1.term = 1
left join StudentResults r2 on d.StudentId = r2.StudentId and r2.term = 2
```

Comment: `PIVOT` seems to be a little more close to what he wants. Also, if he has 3 or 4 TermResults for future data then continuing to self join isn't a good idea in terms of execution, if the table is large.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, yes, I agree PIVOT is probably what OP needs. (This is a more general, core ANSI SQL answer.)

Comment: Two downvotes in 1 minute, on different answers, without any explanation... At least give me an explanation.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, didn't suspect you for a second.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select d.*,
case when r.term=1 then result end as term1result,
case when r.term=2 then result end as term2result,
from StudentDetails d join StudentResults r on 
d.StudentId = r.StudentId
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(

    SELECT sd.StudentID, 
      sd.Name,
      sd.Course,
      'Term' + '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),sr.Term) + '' + 'Result' AS Term
      sr.Result
    FROM StudentDetails sd
    INNER JOIN StudentResults sr
       ON sr.StudentID = sd.StudentID
) AS Data
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Result) FOR Term IN ([Term1Result], [Term2Result])
) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.StudentId, d.Name, d.Course, max(case when r.term =1 then result else null end) as Term1Result, max(case when r.term =2 then result else null end) as Term2Result
FROM StudentDetails d
LEFT JOIN StudentResults r on d.StudentId = r.StudentId
GROUP BY d.StudentId, d.Name, d.Course
```